# Python string match (without string manipulation functions)

Tags: python, string

The other day I got this problem and I think I came out with a very complicated solution. How would you solve it?

Write a function to determine whether an input string x is a substring of another input string y.
For example, "bat" is a substring of "abate", but not of "beat". Basically implement something similar string.substring without using this function or any other similar function (string.find, string.contains, etc)

Comment: `return substring in mainstring`

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  As such, you should probably post your attempt.  And Re: "came out with a very complicated solution", if it works, you might want to try putting it on codereview.stackexchange.com as it would be a more on-topic question for their format I believe.

Comment: Consider including relevant portions of the "very complicated solution" you came up with. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Python makes this very easy, with your example both print statements below will execute:

```
st = "abate"

if "bat" in st:
  print("Yes, this is a substring of st") 
  # do something else

if "xyz" not in st:
  print("No, this isn't a substring of st.") 
  # do something else
```

Comment: `in` will call `__contains__` which is essentially the same kind of thing as `string.find` and so forth which is banned in the (probably homework) question.